# Fody: Cauldron.Interception not found

Tags: c#, fody

I've added Cauldron.Interception.Fody 3.2.3 and Fody 4.2.1 (I'm still using MSBuild 15) to my project via Nuget.

My FodyWeavers.xml file looks like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
  <Cauldron.Interception />
</Weavers>
```

However, when I try to build, I get the following error:

> Fody: No weavers found for the configuration entries Cauldron.Interception. Add the desired weavers via their nuget package.

Why can't Fody find/load the interceptor?

Comment: FYI, I've also tried running this in VS2019 and updating Fody, but it's the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Cauldron.Interception codebase and nuget needs to be updated to the current version of Fody. Currently it is 2 major versions behind